# How can i change PC standard COM port Baud rate?

Tags: bluetooth, iot, com-port

I need to receive data via Com port at 921600bps. But as you can see in the figure [Standard Serial over bluetooth link Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONRx6.png), there is no more than 115200bps as standard. How can this problem be solved?(I want to receive data via the hc05 bluetooth module)

Comment: Do not use vCOM on PC side. Use direct Bluetooth connection (using Bluetooth API) instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there no solution?